# PS4 controller won't connect after connecting to PC

Tags: ps4, controllers

I connected my PS4 controller to my PC and I tried going back on to my console but when I press the button, the sensor light keeps flashing. I pressed reset and also pressed the PS button and share button together but I get nothing.

Comment: this is the same user and I only have 1 controller btw

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that by connecting your PS4 controller (aka. Dualshock 4, or DS4) to your PC, it is now looking for your PC when trying to connect. Switching the DS4 into pairing mode doesn't work either, because your PS4 isn't looking for a controller to pair up with.

Traditionally, consoles would have a sync button, which needs to be pressed at roughly the same time as the sync button on the controller. That way, even if you can no longer use a controller, you can still get your console to pair up. The PS4 (and the Switch) does not have such a button, however. They use a different method to pair up.

**Simply connect your DS4 to your PS4 using a USB cable**, preferably the one that shipped with your console, although apart from a few exceptions (such as the cable from the Xbox Plug & Charge kit) any compatible USB cable will do.

**Once the DS4 is physically connected to the PS4, pressing the Home (PS) button should do the trick.** For best results, make sure your PS4 is turned on and awake. The DS4 should send a signal to the PS4 via the connected USB cable, and re-register to the PS4 as a result. This process can take a couple of seconds. When done, the light on your DS4's light bar should change color from orange (charging) to blue (connected as Player 1).

Once you're done, you can unplug your DS4 and resume playing wirelessly, if you wish. Note that if you want to use your DS4 on PC again, you'll have to repeat the entire pairing process between DS4 and PC, as well as DS4 and PS4 if you wish to go back.